# can not wakeup suspend com[puter

Tags: suspend

I am unable to wake up my suspend Ubuntu 13.10.
I click on suspend accidentally and HD led continues flash, but I tried to press any key keyboard, and CTL-ALT-PS R-E-I-S-U-B and  power button, but can not wake up computer. I had to unplug power and put power back on to reboot computer.

I would like to know are there any way to wake up suspend computer? 
Your help and information is great appreciated,

regards,

Iccsi,

Comment: You can try a fix like the one on the forums here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1978290